# Dual write error when writing data from D365 to CDS

Tags: integration, axapta, x++

I have create a manual entity in F&O which is used for Dual write purpose, it is triggered when workflow is completed for Common > Cases > All cases

However for certain customers I am getting the following error:

Stopped (error): Unable to write data to entity incidents.Writes to ### failed with error message Request failed with status code BadRequest and CDS error code : 0x8006088a response message: Bad Request - Error in query syntax...

Can anyone please help me understand this and provide some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this happens when you try to update/insert value in lookup field on CDS. You need to give entity type (schema name) and then it's guid. [Look at this article](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/CDS-Error-quot-0x8006088a-quot/td-p/757026) this will give you more idea. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the same problem, however I had an issue with Dual-Write when tried to create legal entities and I've managed it by performing these steps:

1 Stop the Dual-Write mapping which synchronize the data with cdm_company table.
2 Delete all records in cdm_Company table (this is Dataverse table, you can find it in Power Apps)
3 In Dual-Write settings, You have to choose the owning team. Please note, that the only team we could use to solve the issue was the security group which is made in Azure Active Directory.
4 Start The Dual-Write mapping with Initial Sync and Choose Finance and Operations as the master.

The error is shown below. If You face the same issue, these steps might help you.[image: Error]